# POST enviado por ajax fica vazio no php

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Olá, estou fazendo um sistema de login com ajax, que é ativado com um botão, porem estou tendo problemas, pois os dados enviados pelo ajax, que são o nome de usuário e a senha, não existem ou estão vazios no PHP, já tentei corrigir isso de vários jeitos olhei em vários sites, e não consigo resolver. Alguém poderia me ajudar, estou as uns dois dias assim, sou iniciante ainda. Agradeço antecipadamente.

HTML

```
<div id="login_inputs_top_menu">
    <label id="login_inputs_label_top_menu">
        Nome de usuario
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="input_user_top_menu">
    <label id="login_inputs_label_top_menu">
        Senha
    </label>
    <input type="password" id="input_password_top_menu">
</div>
<button id="submit_login_button">Login</button><br>
```

Jquery

```
$("#submit_login_button").click(function () {  
        var user_name = $("#input_user_top_menu").val();
        var password = $("#input_password_top_menu").val();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            data:{
                user_name: user_name,
                password: password
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response.output);
            }
        });
    });
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_SESSION)){
echo "Você ja fez login";
}else{
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$userName = $_POST['user_name'];
$password = $_POST['password'];  
}
```

Com o debuger do chrome eu vejo que o PHP, a partir do que pedi para ele informar, ele sempre retorna o método como GET, sendo que pedi POST, e retorna que os POST que foram enviados são nulos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é "erro de digitação", no jQuery para informar o método **não** usamos **`method:`**, isso esta errado:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
```

O **correto** é `type:`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
```

Vale ressaltar que no jQuery 1.9+ existe o "aliases" (apelido) para o `type:` que é `method:`, se vier a atualizar seu jQuery para as versões mais recentes o `method:` irá funcionar

Comment: vlw, vou tentar aqui

Comment: Obrigado, funcinou, so que agora tem outro problema, a parte do codigo que verifica se as variaveis estao vazias, "if( empty(..." esta ainda dizendo que elas estao vazias, sendo que se eu faço eco das variaveis ele os dados aparecem.

Comment: @VictorGomez faz um `var_dump` antes de tudo no php, assim: `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: A consegui ver qual era o problema, obrigado.